# Distribution of the minimum

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the following problem, given a random variable $X$ with density
$$f(x)=2x\text{ for }x\in(0,1)$$
and a r.s.s. $X_1, X_2, X_3$. I have to calculate the probability that $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ exceeds the median $M$.

Previously I have computed the distribution of $X_{(1)}$, so I get this
$$P(X_{(1)}>M)=1-F_{X_{(1)}}(M)=(1-F(M))^3=\frac{1}{8}$$
since by definition $F(M)=\frac{1}{2}$.

The thing that makes me doubt about my result is that I haven't used the density of $f$ at all, does that mean this is true for every random variable, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the same answer for any *continuously distributed* random variable. For let $M$ be *a median* (medians need not be unique). The probability that $X_i$ is $\gt M$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. The probability that the minimum is $\gt M$ is therefore $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$.

*Remark:* Things can break down if the distribution is not continuous. For example, let us suppose that the $X_i$ are independent and take on the values $-1$, $0$, and $1$ with equal probability. The median is $0$, but the probability the minimum is greater than $0$ is $\frac{1}{3^3}$.

Comment: So it is just the problem has more information than needed, that kind of things always get me.

Comment: @Smurf: But you had no problem, since you computed *successfully* using the cdf. Then you raised the very good question about whether one really needed to know the distribution.